# Trouble loading nanoFramework app onto STM32F429I-DISC1 board

Tags: nanoframework

I am trying to run a simple .NET nanoFrameork HelloWorld application on STM32F429I-DISC1 board (https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/reference-targets/stm32f429i-discovery.html).

I followed the steps from here:  https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/getting-started-guides/getting-started-managed.html, but I cannot see my board in the Device Explorer window.

I installed nanoFramework using the ST-Link utility following the steps here: https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/stm32/flash-stlink.html

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the target name that's used in the build. For this board that's ST_STM32F429I_DISCOVERY.

The target names are in the targets list in the home repo in github. From your question I can see that should be also mentioned on the target description page. Another improvement to add to the todo list...

Comment: Did the above helped you? If yes, please up vote the answer.